# Adding pointers with size_t type value

Tags: c++, pointers, types, size-t

```
class CheckPointer {
public:
    CheckPointer(int * mbeg, int * mend) :
        beg(mbeg), end(mend), curr(mbeg) {}

    // subscript operator
    int & operator[] (const size_t pos) {
        if (beg + pos < beg) {
            throw out_of_range("ERR: before beg!");
        }
        if (beg + pos >= end)
            throw out_of_range("ERR: end or past end!");
        return *(const_cast<int *>(beg + pos));
    }
private:
    const int * beg;
    const int * end;
    int * curr;
};
```

I have defined a subscript operator for the class CheckPointer. As the @param pos is of type size_t, I cannot check whether the user has passed a positive or negative value. Howerver I try to write the code to do the bound-check instead and it works :

```
        if (beg + pos < beg) {
            throw out_of_range("ERR: before beg!");
        }
```

I don't know why it works... Could any one help me?

Thank you for considering my question!

---

For more information:

Environment: eclipse CDT, Ubuntu 10.04

test-code:

```
int iarr[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
CheckPointer cp(iarr, iarr+6);
// subscript
cout << cp[2] << endl;
cout << cp[5] << endl;
cout << cp[-2] << endl; // error: before beg
```

test-code_output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  ERR: before beg!
3
6
```

Comment: FWIW, this is a bad idea. Faulty pointers are a **bug** in the code, they shouldn’t lead to an exception (which is an unexpected, but not unprepared situation in code). Bad pointers shouldn’t be prepared for, they should be prevented. If you want to improve debuggability of your code, do an `assert` instead (or, in fact, rely on your system’s debugger for exactly that). Additionally, the `const_cast` is simply semantically wrong here. Don’t store pointers to `const`, store `const` pointers. And finally, `beg` is never used. Remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works because the negative value is cast to an unsigned value.  Your machine architecture probably uses two's-complement for negative values, so a value of -2 results in:

```
0xfffffffe (assuming 32-bit)
```

When you add this to `beg`, it wraps around and provided `beg` is greater than or equal to 2, has the effect of subtracting 2 from it.  Thus, despite the index being extremely large, it has essentially performed a subtraction.  If the value of `beg` was `1` or `0`, the error would be "past end" instead.

Comment: The conversion from signed to unsigned doesn't depend on machine architecture: "If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — end note ]"

Answer (score 1):

Formally, comparing `beg + pos` to `beg` has undefined behavior if `beg + pos` is outside the array that starts at `beg` (that's slightly simplified, but sufficient for this discussion). A better check for a bad index would be:

```
if (end - beg <= pos)
```

But that doesn't answer the question. Converting small negative values to `size_t` produces large positive values; treating them as offsets produces a pointer that's well past the end of the array, so checking whether the result is in bounds will find this problem as well as "ordinary" values that are simply beyond the end.